# Binary stdin and stdout

Tags: text, binary, stdout, stdin

I'm looking to write a pair of utilities that read in a newline separated list of integers on stdin and output their binary (4 byte) equivalent to stdout, and vice versa.

My first thought was a simple bash/linux command that would do this, but I was unable to find one.  My second thought was to do this in C++, but I can't figure out how to change stdin or stdout to a binary stream.

Any thoughts on a good way to do this?  I'm impartial to any particular programming language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, you could just try:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print pack 'i', $_;'
```

That will give you a host native signed integer of at least 32 bits, but possibly more depending on your local C compiler.

Other options to pack can go in place of the `'i'`, such as `'l'` which will give you a signed long, which should be 32-bits.  And there yet more options for little-endian or big-endian.

For the full description, please see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html.

And here's your solution in C, in case you want to do it the boring way.  `:)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   int x;

   while (fscanf(stdin, "%i", &x)) {
      fwrite(&x, sizeof(x), 1, stdout);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to "change stdout to binary", just output binary to it. This will certainly confuse e.g. a terminal emulator connected to that stream, but that is to be expected.

A plain loop of `fscanf()` to read each integer, followed by a `fwrite()` to write it out should work. Beware of endianness issues though, you might want to output each byte separately.

Comment: It's worth mentioning endian-ness (that's why Unix prefers text), though where you are piping to a program, both are on the same machine.  If you used a socket instead (to a program on a separate machine) - then endian-ness comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix and its derivatives, there is no need to be concerned about whether the stdin or stdout are 'binary' mode - binary and text modes are the same.  I've not conducted extensive testing on Windows, but under Cygwin, I've not noticed any issues there, either.

Comment: Right, I guess my problem was that I didn't understand how to output the number "in binary mode".  'cout << 256;' will output the 3 ascii characters "256" not the binary equivalent.

Comment: @Rich: yes; cout assumes text and converts stuff to text by default.  The analog of C's `fwrite()` should be used instead.